# The Largest/Smallest Outputs do not showcase the right values

Tags: java

Should receive an output of the largest/smallest numbers within the inputs, what seems to be the problem? I have tried looking it up online, the source code appears to be the same. Thank you for your assistance.

**Source code:**

```
package counting.largest.smallest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingLargestSmallest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner TheN = new Scanner(System.in);

        int counter = 0;
        int number;
        int smallest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int largest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        while (counter < 10) {
            System.out.print("Integer=");

            number = TheN.nextInt();
            counter++;

            if (number < smallest) {
                number = smallest;
            } else if (number > largest) {
                number = largest;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nSmallest=" + smallest);
        System.out.println("Largest=" + largest);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Integer=1
Integer=2
Integer=3
Integer=4
Integer=5
Integer=6
Integer=7
Integer=8
Integer=9
Integer=10

Smallest=-2147483648
Largest=2147483647
```

Comment: Hint: where do you expect to be assigning different values to `smallest` and `largest`? What are you *actually* assigning in those places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there were 3 bugs:

1.

```
int smallest=Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
int largest=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

2. 

```
number=smallest;
number=largest;
```

3. Using `else if`

1: When you want to find a `min` number keep it `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and when you want to find `max` keep it has `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Why for `min` we Initialize `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and for `max` we Initialize `Integer.MIN_VALUE`?

Say you want to multiple `n` numbers from the user. So we will declare and initialize `mul` variable to `1`. cause we know any `number` multiple by 1 will give us the same `number`.
Whereas if we initialize `mul` with `0` it will give us `0` only.
So we say `1` for multiplication is `identity`.
Similarly, for finding `Minimum` number we use an identity that is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.
So that number that `less` then `Integer.MAX_VALUE` are saved in `Samllest` variable.

```
 int smallest=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Similarly for `max` we `initialize` it with `Integer.MIN_VALUE` SO that number  that are `greater` then `Integer.MIN_VALUE` are stored in `largest` variable.

```
int largest=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

2:  You are assigning `number` variable the value of `smallest` and  `largest` it should be like `smallest=number` and `largest=number`
when you write `x=0` it says x is 0 that means x is changed, Similarly when you write `number=smallest` its `number = Integer.MAX_VALUE` and smallest is not changing at all.
So you should write like `smallest = number`, It means smallest is the number and `smallest` is changing every time condition  `satisfies`.

3: When you write

```
if(condition){

}else if(conditon){

}
```

`else if` is only excuted when first `if` statement if `false` and if first `condition` is `true` second `if` is never executed.
if we have descending number then second `if` will never be excuted which would result in having `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in `largest` variable.
And here you want to check for both `min` and `max` so we should have indepent `if` statement for each

```
if(condition){

}
if(condition){

}
```

Code:

```
            Scanner TheN= new Scanner(System.in);  
            int counter=0;
            int number;
            // changed
            int smallest=Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
            int largest=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            while(counter<10){
                  System.out.print("Integer=");     
                  number=TheN.nextInt();    
                  counter++;
                  if(number<smallest){
                     // changed  
                     smallest= number;
                  }
                  if(number>largest){
                     // changed  
                     largest=number;
                 }
            }
            System.out.println("\nSmallest="+smallest);
            System.out.println("Largest="+largest);
```

Output:

```
Integer=1
Integer=2
Integer=2
Integer=4
Integer=3
Integer=6
Integer=7
Integer=8
Integer=9
Integer=10

Smallest=1
Largest=10
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Could you please go into detail about why the counter++; is crucial in this code?

Comment: @BroJaek so when we write `while loop`  it needs a condition,  and if `condition` is `true` while loop will `execute` and it `while loop` condition is false then while loop will not be `executed`. So if we get into a `while loop` its necessary to get out of it too, if the condition is always `true` Then the `while loop` will never `end`, so in order to come out of the `while loop` we check `counter < 10` and increment the counter by 1 so that when the counter is `10 ` we get out of the while loop.

Comment: Ohhhh, now I understand! Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: it did then just accept the answer so that others facing the same issue can review the answer.